# In monopoly deal, if I have 3 black cards & one is a wild property. Can a player using a sly deal ask for the wild property or can I choose what card?

Tags: monopoly-deal

Does the person playing a sly deal card get to choose the specific card or just the group color?

Answer (score 0):

**They can take the wild card.**

The exact wording of the card ([as seen here](https://www.sl-web.site/resources/pdf/instructionsMonopolyDeal.pdf)) is as follows:

> **Steal a property** from any other player and add it to your property collection.  You cannot steal a card from a full set of properties.  Can also be banked as money.

The only limitation is that the property may not be from a complete set.  There is nothing which mentions group colour.  Property Wild Cards are still property cards.

Answer (score 0):

The player playing the card chooses the property to steal. The card text says "Steal a property", not something like "Choose a color and an opponent. That opponent chooses a property of that color..."

This is confirmed on [this page](https://monopolydealstrategy.com/index.php?page=sly):

> When using a Sly Deal or Force Deal to take an opponent’s property and they have multiple of the color you want, always choose the wild card if they have one.